# How do I view the parsed RSS output?

Tags: templates, rss

It's probably a dumb question, but it doesn't matter what browser I open my podcast rss feed in it doesn't show any content. The feed validates in a validator, but I just want to be able to see the code without have to go to a validator to get it.

The link is: http://dev.ncctk.com/feeds/lynden-sermon-audio

Comment: [Looks fine to me](http://cl.ly/image/011J3p333H0E) in Firefox.

Comment: What browser are you using? I see the raw XML in Chrome, and formatted feed content in Firefox. Safari decided to launch Mail.app for me today when I loaded it. Different browsers have different methods of rendering a feed.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try viewing the source code in your browser?